# Unable to get ethernet and WiFi working on Raspberry Pi4

Tags: networking, internet

I am trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 on an Raspberry Pi 4 but when I log in, it says that the internet connection is down check your internet settings or proxy.

I am using both ethernet and WiFi but it doesn't seem to work. I am using a 1GB model and I can't install packages because I'm not connected to internet.

Comment: forgot to mention using 32bit version 64bit did not work

Comment: Please edit your question. Provide links to 1) The directions or instructions that you are following and 2) Where you got that 32-bit Ubuntu install image from. Please use the '[edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1190944/edit)' link instead of adding comments to your own question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.